# Deleted \home, files were backed up, computer froze and now I can't log in

Tags: 17.10

I was trying to install a program in home and it screwed up my \home directory. All my files were backed up but now I can't use any file manager to organize everything again. Also I don't know if I messed something up and would like to know how to proceed without damaging even more my computer. The files were moved to a folder called backupdir-8866.

Update: My computer froze and a had to force shut down, now I can't log in, I enter my password and it sends me back to the log in screen. I need urgent help.

Update: I entered in recovery mode, i used `ls /home` and it is empty, before i forced shut down there was the folder i mentioned with all my files, i am not sure what to do.

Update: In shell prompt I ran `locate username` and it returned `/home/username`, but `ls /home` returns nothing.

Comment: `locate` command creates a database of files on the system, so from its perspective the files exist since the database has not been updated.

Comment: You have also mentioned that the files were **moved** to a folder called `backupdir-8866`, was it moved or copied? Also where was it located the backup location?

Comment: I think they were moved since I had a very big amount of information that appeared in that folder in seconds, i was looking at the home folder when the program was installing and cancel the installation when I saw everything disappear and the folder i mentioned appear. It was supposedly located at `\home\BackupDir-8866\username`.

Comment: Note that the directory seperator in Linux is the forward slash `/`, not backward slash `\\` that you have typed in your question and comment.

Comment: Can update the necessary information in the question? Also can you also check if the disk usage has changed or something(If you have some shell access to the system)?

Comment: I have been using the forward dash in all my commands, I think stress made me write it wrong here. I do have shell access via recovery mode but i don't know how to check if the disk usage has changed. Right now the most urgent thing I need is to login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command `sudo mkhomedir_helper <username>`. That should recreate the user folder with the right permissions and minimum required dot files.

Alternatively you could try the following, which should have the same effect:

```
sudo mkdir /home/username
sudo cp /etc/skel/* /home/username/
sudo chown -R username:username /home/username
```

Comment: @JuanDavid since you are in `recovery mode` the file-system has been mounted in `read-only` mode, I would recommend trying to find the files from the shell in recovery mode if they have moved.

Comment: I used `crtl+alt+f1` in the login screen and did as you said, I can know log in which was the most urgent worry.